# Printing in php with php_printer.dll

Tags: php, printing, printers, network-printers

i am using php_priner.dll.

I get print formatted text with different sizes and styles.

my problem come when i want align text anywhere.

not print any kind of text

this is how I do it

**printing correctly**

```
$printer = printer_open("name print");
if ($printer){
printer_start_doc($printer, "NewTickect");
printer_start_page($printer); 
$lfont = printer_create_font("Arial", 10, 8, PRINTER_FW_BOLD, false, false, false, 0);
printer_select_font($printer, $lfont);
printer_set_option($printer, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
 printer_draw_text($printer, $text,0,0);
printer_delete_font($lfont);
printer_end_page($printer);
printer_end_doc($printer);
printer_close($printer);
}
```

**follows nothing prints**

```
 $printer = printer_open("name print");
    if ($printer){
    printer_start_doc($printer, "NewTickect");
    printer_start_page($printer); 
    $lfont = printer_create_font("Arial", 10, 8, PRINTER_FW_BOLD, false, false, false, 0);
    printer_select_font($printer, $lfont);
    printer_set_option($printer, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");

    //this is the new line
    printer_set_option($printer, PRINTER_TEXT_ALIGN, PRINTER_TA_CENTER);

    printer_draw_text($printer, $text,0,0);
    printer_delete_font($lfont);
    printer_end_page($printer);
    printer_end_doc($printer);
    printer_close($printer);
    }
```

this is all that I need to print correctly as I will
¿anyone knows that this is due?
I'm not capar to find solution
thanks, greetings

UPDATE 07/04/2014:

I wonder if anyone knows a better way to do this.
want to print on Bixolon srp 275 tickes connected by usb through php.
help me please 
thanks

Comment: where did you get php_printer.dll, can be from this one https://github.com/maryo/php-5.5-windows-extensions/blob/master/php_printer-0.1.0-dev-5.5-vc11-x86/php_printer_nts.dll ?

Comment: OK, got from this: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have set a width for the page, so it can't align. set a width using PRINTER_PAPER_WIDTH parameter. noticed that it uses integer and unit is mm.
take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-set-option.php